# Spring Hessian Exception

Tags: java, spring, hessian

Im looking into handling recovery from Spring Hessian connection being down. What are the exceptions possible that hessian proxy can throw if the connection is down?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample stack trace that you'll get every time you’ll try to connect to a hessian remote service which is unavailable:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.springframework.remoting.RemoteConnectFailureException: Cannot connect to Hessian remote service at [http://localhost:17026/remoting/TestService]; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianClientInterceptor.convertHessianAccessException(HessianClientInterceptor.java:262)
    at org.springframework.remoting.caucho.HessianClientInterceptor.invoke(HessianClientInterceptor.java:235)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy1.getNameFromKassa(Unknown Source)
…

BTW, the hessian proxy won't throw you any exception for the simple reason of being down ;)